# Rate of convergence when substituting sequence by its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (w_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, (w_n')_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ sequences of complex numbers with $|z_n| = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Assume that $z_n \to z$ and $w_n \to w, w_n' \to w'$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(z w) = \mathrm{Re}(z w')$.

Clearly, $\mathrm{Re}(z_n (w_n - w_n') ) \to 0$. Suppose that there exists $a > 1$ such that $a^n \mathrm{Re}(z_n (w_n - w_n') ) \to 0$. Is it true that $a^n \mathrm{Re}(z (w_n - w_n') ) \to 0$? If the answer is negative, does there exist $a > b > 1$ such that $b^n \mathrm{Re}(z (w_n - w_n') ) \to 0$?